# nginx+uwsgi+django, there seems to be some strange cache in uwsgi, help me

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

This is uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]  
uid = 500
listen=200
master = true  
profiler = true 
processes = 8 
logdate = true  
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000  
module = www.wsgi  
pythonpath = /root/www/
pythonpath = /root/www/www 
pidfile = /root/www/www.pid  
daemonize = /root/www/www.log  
enable-threads = true
memory-report = true
limit-as = 6048
```

This is Nginx config:

```
server{  
    listen 80;  
    server_name 119.254.35.221;      
    location / {  
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;  
        include uwsgi_params;  
    }  
}
```

The django works ok, but modifed pages can't be seen unless i restart uwsgi.(what's more, as i config 8 worker process, i can see the modified page when i press on ctrl+f5 for a while, seems that only certain worker can read and response the modified page, but others just shows the old one, who caches the old page? i didn't config anything about cache)

I didn't config the django, and it works well with "python manager runserver ...", but havfe this problem when working with nginx+uwsgi.

(the nginx and uwsgi are both new installation, i'm sure nothing else is configed here..)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, Apache (eg. in embedded mode) behaves similarly.

Answer (score 5):

- uwsgi does not reload your code automatically, only development server does
- runserver is for debug purposes, uwsgi and nginx for production
- in production you can restart uwsgi by `service uwsgi restart` or via init.d script
- there is even better way to reload uwsg by using [touch-reload](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Management)

usually there is no need to cleanup `.pyc` files, it happens only when timestamps on files are wrong (I've seen it only couple times at my entire carieer)

Comment: I was using `uwsgi-emperor` instead of a `uwsgi` daemon, so I had to issue `sudo service uwsgi-emperor reload` instead. I opted to just use the manage.py runserver for dev use though; since its built for that kind of use.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. `uwsgi` will not re-read your code unless you restart it (it does not work like `runserver` when you have `DEBUG=True`).

If after you have updated your code, restarted uwsgi, cleared your browser cache and it *still* doesn't reflect your changes, then you should delete `*.pyc` files from your source directory.

I typically use this:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;
```

Roughly speaking, `.pyc` is the "compiled" version of your code. Python will load this optimized version if it doesn't detect a change in the source. If you delete these files; then it will re-read your source files.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help ! Should I use manager.py when i develop and debug with my project ?

Comment: Yes; use uwsgi+nginx only for deployment. `runserver` was developed especially for development.