# changed made in css not loading in django project?

Tags: python, css, django, frontend, web-deployment

I am working on projects first i made front-end which i integrate with django. I copy my style sheet in django and set important SETTINGS.then i run server which work fine for me. CSS load properly.But when add some more CSS in my style file this is not loading,please help me?

> **setting.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django won't refresh staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911070/django-wont-refresh-staticfiles)

Comment: previous css is loading properly.Only new css is not loading.

Comment: i only del my browser cache, now i load my admin page it give error page not found

Comment: what type of enviroment do you have? are you in production?

Comment: also have you collected the static files since updating?