# Django: cannot update css changes

Tags: html, css, django

After running my server, my page doesn't show the updates that I've made in the CSS file.

My navbar won't recognize a css rule: `.navbar-bg {background-color: black;}` (i've just tested this rule).

However, If I paste this same `HTML` and `CSS` code in a site like CodePen it works (my navbar gets a black background).

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/KbKzQo

The same happens if I run the HTML and CSS from a directory in my PC, so I think it has something to do with Django.

**What could it be?**

I've tried also this other answer:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
```

from here (without results):

[Django won't refresh staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911070/django-wont-refresh-staticfiles)

**base.html**:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription %}{% endblock %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    {#    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"#}
    {#          integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">#}
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <div class="container">

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        <div class="container-fluid nav-bar-fixed-top my_top_navbar_div">


            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

**navbar.html:**

```
<!--- GALLITO NAVBAR --->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">


        <ul id="mi_menu" class="navbar-nav mr-auto my_custom_menu">

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Etiquetas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magnetos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empaques</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </li>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item active">
{#                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>#}
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ user }}</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item active">
{#                    <a class="nav-link" href={% url 'login' %}>LogIn</a>#}
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registro</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</nav>
```

**custom.css:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* === NavBar === */
.nav-item {
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.dropdown-item {

}


/* == Footer ==== */

.my_footer {
    background-color: #5a6268;
}

.my_footer p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/* == Category Page == */

.my_row_class {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.my_row_class .mx-auto p {

    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.my_row_class .mx-auto p a {

    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.my_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.my_title {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
}

.my_image_padding {
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.my_bottom_margin {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-body h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
}

/*=== Product Page ==*/

.my_prod_row_class {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.my_prod_row_class .mx-auto p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.my_prod_row_class .mx-auto p a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.my_prod_title {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.my_prod_text {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.my_search_text {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/*== Cart ==*/


.my_custom_table {
    min-width: 400px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.my_custom_thead {

    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    background-color: #f8f9fa !important;

}

.custom_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.custom_a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.custom_icon {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}

.my_custom_button {

    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-bg {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I see that my new css class: `.navbar-bg` is not beeing loaded. Why is that? and How can I solve it? (CTRL + F5 doesn't solve this).

Also, this happens in Chrome and in Firefox (I'm using Ubuntu).

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**(settings.py)

```
"""
Django settings for perfectcushion project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^_67&#r+(c+%pu&n+a%&dmxql^i^_$0f69)mnhf@)zq-rbxe9z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'search_app',
    'cart',
    'stripe',
    'order',
    'crispy_forms',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'perfectcushion.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search_app', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/'),]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processor.menu_links',
                'cart.context_processor.counter'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'perfectcushion.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')


### Stripe Settings ###


STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 'pk_test_N0ksyIuO5d1ulLDuoMlLiU26'

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_fFHncrzOzBPS3XxDQM0TWMfy'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

**UPDATE 3**:

Creating `static_dirs` inside `static` folder and then changing this:

```
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )
```

and then doing `collecstatic` doesn't make effect:

```
manage.py@perfectcushion > collectstatic
bash -cl "/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/projects_envs/perfectcushion_env/bin/python /home/ogonzales/Escritorio/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py collectstatic /home/ogonzales/Escritorio/web_proyects/perfectcushion"
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/ogonzales/Escritorio/web_proyects/perfectcushion/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:  yes

0 static files copied to '/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/web_proyects/perfectcushion/staticfiles', 119 unmodified.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**UPDATE 4:** Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: Try viewing the source of your app from the browser and then click on the css link and see if the correct css file is loaded.

Comment: `href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}?20181209">`

Comment: Can you copy the settings.py file here

Comment: Might be due to browser cache. Try hitting a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: @MiniGunnR Please, see update 1.

Comment: @MohammadAli Please, see update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

`STATIC_ROOT` is supposed to be **destination** folder for `collectstatic` command. That's where files will be copied from source directories.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is the [list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) of **source** folders for `collectstatic`. Additional folders. Because all the subfolders named `static` from any app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` will be searched [automatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) by default. Which means - even thirdparty apps, e.g. DRF or whatever.

Again, in `STATICFILES_DIRS` you should list any source folders with staticfiles which **are not `/static/` subfolders of your django project apps**. E.g. if you have somewhere `/home/me/my_super_imgs/` and config:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/opt/prod/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/me/my_super_imgs/',
)
```

you will have all the files and subfolders of `my_super_imgs` inside `/var/opt/prod/static/` after executing `collectstatic`. As well as all any content from `/static/` subfolder of all the apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

If you have `shop/static/` folder - its contents will be "collected" into `staticfiles` by default.

Note, you are trying to load static files under `/static/` url in your template, but your destination folder is named as `staticfiles`. It's okay because you have configured both STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL, but may confuse because you have `/static/` folder as well.

One more thing:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search_app', 'templates/'),
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/'),]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
```

stop listing your **app dirs** here - `APP_DIRS` is enabled and this is enough.

## upd

Why browser does not reflect css file changes?

There are many levels of caching between file on server's disk and rendered page on client-side. By doing this trick `href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}?20181209">` (see question symbol?) as I mentioned in comment under your question, you are changing full URL and it forces reloading of css (or any other) file, whilst physical file name is not changed. Update date after `?` when file changed. This is a well known trick. This value may be date or hash of this file.

Also, you may introduce template tag like `{% my_css %}` which would insert static file names with defined date/hash/build parameter in the URL - to avoid copying this magic parameter into many templates.

Right now you may test reloading css file with parameter manually:

- update css file
- check that browser does not see changes by opening css file url
- open the same url with any `?parameter`
- done, file content refreshed

Comment: I see your point. Please, see my update 4, I just have 1 static folder at project level. I guess I need to have 1 inside each app (at least in the shop app?). 

Also, please, explain a little better the "Note" part in your answer. Where in my template Am I doing that?

Comment: I suggest to set STATIC_ROOT to some place outside of project folder. Right now everything is at one place and may confuse. Just for understanding what goes where. Then, `print(BASE_DIR)` - my guess is that it is `.../web_proyects/perfectcusion/perfectcusion/` and combined with `/static/` will not match your `perfectcusion/static/` folder.

Comment: Now I see what you say in your comment about loading staticfiles. So according to your suggestion (and beeing staticfiles folder the final destination of all my static files -from different aps-, I should `"{% staticfiles 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"` instead of  `"{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"`

Comment: BASE_DIR is `/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/web_proyects/perfectcushion`

Comment: `I should "{% staticfiles 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"` no, there is no such command. `static` is a function (template tag) name here. Now clear `staticfiles` and run `collectstatic`.

Comment: Ok, deleted all files inside `staticfiles` folder and run `collectstatics`. Now I have all the files from `static` folder copied in `staticfiles` folder.  My problem was that I was modifiying things directly in `staticfiles` folder, when I should have modified things in `static` folder and then call `collecstatic`. 

However, Why modifiying things in `staticfiles` folder is not recognized when calling runserver? (changes don't take place in css file por example). My logic is that it should because `staticfiles` folder is the end destination of all static files (css files included).

Comment: Why changing CSS file in `staticfiles` folder doesn't reflect in browsers? (make a new css class but when inspecting sources -in Chrome or Firefox- it doesn't appear there). As if weren't created at all, againg beeing this folder the end destination of all static files.

Comment: thank you, one more point, after this talk I think the best method is to make all changes in statics folders in your apps, because if you make them directly en staticfiles folder and also in static folders of your apps, and then call `collectstatics`, the laters will override your changes in staticfiles folder files. I have to test this, correct me if I'm not correct.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't modify files directly in `staticfiles` folder.

Answer (score 5):

is not that! it happened to me the exact same thing! is the cache (facepalm)

Try it in incognito mode and you will see the changes in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can test this method. I hope would be benefit for you

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )
```

Then add you can static files in static/static_dirs folders.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I found is that if:

1) Changing `custom.css` file in `staticfiles/css` and then running: `collecstatic` wouldn't update the custmo.css in `static/css` folder.

This is why my update wasn't reflecting on the different browsers.

2) Even if I delete `custom.css` in `static/css` and then run `collecstatic` to create/update `custom.css`, it does not happen. And the browser doesn't reflect the changes in the css file I want.

3) The solution, at the moment for me, is to make the modifications directly in the `static/css` folder, to be exact here: `static/css/custom.css`, and then the changes are visible in browser, in the case, having the navbar background in black.

Is this how it is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**
after saving your static files (the `main.css` file for exemple), kill the running web server and clean the page by clicking `ctrl+c` , and rerun the server by executing this command in your terminal/cmd

```
python manage.py runserver
```

finally, reload the web page in the browser

**solution 2:**
try to clear your browser cache after each modification of your static files (css, js, media or font)

[image]

you can find this in (if you use google chrome) Settings> Privacy and security> Clear browsing data

Comment: there is another solution, is by using google chrome incognito (private navigator)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The mistake I made was making changes in the statics folder of the main project instead of the static folder of my app.

When I changed CSS in the app folder and run `collectstatics` changes got reflected.

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

*I had a similar problem, just move your CSS file to a new file with another name, for exemple main.css to main2.css and put main2.css in the static place of the old main.css , finally restart the server.*