# How to refresh react frontend files generated by webpack in django templates?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack-4

I used webpack to convert react to static files and render them in django templates but even though the static files are changed the website rendered by django is same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: cannot update css changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689833/django-cannot-update-css-changes)

Comment: See `upd` part in the answer. About additional parameter. For bundles it can be a date or a hash/MD5.

Comment: The webpack compiled the file correctly but django is still serving the old js.I tried restarting the server.the js is loading but an older version of it

Comment: I understood, this is a common case, I gave you the solution, please follow the link and take a look at the answer.